# What material is Jean Grey's animated series costume made of?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-the-animated-series

I started re-watching some old episodes of the old *X-Men: The Animated Series* TV show the other day and started thinking about this: What material is the gold and blue outfit that Jean wears made out of?

At times, it looks like it might be metal, but other times it seems almost like something a little different. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Pixels....it's made of pixels!

Comment: [Spandex, probably](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJz0L73t6i4)

Comment: @Valorum-See, that's what I was thinking; just wondering if the material was ever named in any of the source material.

Answer (score 4):

### Unstable Molecules (most likely)

In the iconic intro to the Animated series, and at least once during the series, Storm transforms from civilian clothing into her X-Men Uniform:

[image: Storm transforming from civilian clothes to her uniform in a flash of lightning]

According to [this eagle-eyed redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/3f86v6/comment/ctm8ij1/) this has been explained in the comics as Storm manipulating the unstable molecules in her costume.

How is this related to Jean Grey? In the scans they provide, it shows Storm manipulating the clothing of *all* the x-men.

It seems reasonable, that if they have copied over Storm's unstable molecule clothing, they would have done so for everybody, Jean included.

[image: Storm uses her powers to transform her costume in X-Men Vol 1 #101]
[X-Men Vol 1 #101](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_1_101)<sup>1</sup>

---

1. note that although in this image Scott says Jean has 'created her costume out of nothing', that is in fact

> Phoenix

And even so, I don't recall Jean doing this trick in any of the animated series.

Comment: Coincidentally, unstable molecules was my nickname at university